# Simulate Battery for Bluetooth Device

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, simulation

I have a little bluetooth to aux in my car which is battery powered. I want to hook it up directly without the usb cable hanging when charging. The problem is that I can't leave it always connected because when fully charged, it makes an annoying sound. I am pretty new so correct me if I'm wrong but, could I make a battery simulator/emulator circuit so that the device thinks it is always around 50%? That way it should not make any sound right? If there is a simpler solution, I'm open to ideas. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What kind of annoying sound?

Comment: It's like an "I'm charged" sound. In order for you to know and unplug the device.

Comment: Will the device not run with the battery disconnected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the device it likely has a small lithium ion battery that has a nominal voltage of 3.7V. It goes down to 2.8V and charges up to 4.2V. The board likely has a charging IC with some cut off voltage to alert, over charge protection. There is likely only two wires to the battery.

You could trick it by connecting a regulated 3.5 to 3.7 volt supply instead of the battery ***And making sure you never connect the usb power supply***. Using the usb 5v supply with an adjustable linear regulator like the lm7805 should work.

This is not guaranteed though.